# Is there a command which applies Position[] to each element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of elements, I want to produce something similar to `Tally`, but instead of counting how many times each element occurs in the list, I instead want a list of positions at which each element occurs.

> My question is: is there an in-built command which does this?

It's easy enough to implement by applying `Position[list,#]&` to each entry I suppose, but it feels like there should be a built-in command, I just can't seem to come across it.

**Example:** For clarity, suppose the command is called `Positions[]`. I want it to do the following:

```
In[1]:= Positions[{1,3,2,1,1,2,3,1}]
Out[1]= {{1,{1,4,5,8}}, {3,{2,7}}, {2,{3,6}}}
```

Comment: Look at `PositionIndex`...

Comment: @ciao Thanks! I'd been scrolling through the help window for ages but never came across it for some mysterious reason.

Comment: `l = {1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1}
PositionIndex[l] /. {Rule -> List, Association -> List}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
l = {1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1}
PositionIndex[l]
KeyValueMap[List, %]
```

> <|1 -> {1, 4, 5, 8}, 3 -> {2, 7}, 2 -> {3, 6}|>

> {{1, {1, 4, 5, 8}},{3, {2, 7}}, {2, {3, 6}}}